# Who to collect information from multi tables with condition in SQL language

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables in my database

```
courses                                  degree_plan
--------------------                   ------------------------                
course     course_no                    major        course_no 
--------------------                   ------------------------
CHEM101        1                        COE               1
Math101        2                        SWE               1
                                        SWE               2

student                                  equal
-------------------------------     ---------------------------------------- 
course_no      ID       grade        course_no   course    equivalent    ID
-------------------------------     ----------------------------------------
1              5544      A            1        CHEM101    chemistry 1   5544 
1              5533      A            2        Math101   mathematics 1  5533
2              5533      B
```

I wrote this query

```
    SELECT courses .course,equal.equivalent ,equal.id FROM courses LEFT JOIN 
equal ON equal.Course_no=courses.course_no
    LEFT JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.no =courses.no LEFT JOIN student 
    ON courses.no= student.no AND student.id=5533 WHERE degree_plan.major='SWE';
```

when I run it give me like this

```
----------------------------------------------
course      equivalent       equal.id 
----------------------------------------------
CHEM101    Digital design    5544 
Math101    mathematics 1     5533
```

I do not want that because give me (Digital design    5544) which for another student 
I want give me like the table in the below

I want like this

```
----------------------------------------------
course      equivalent       equal.id 
----------------------------------------------
CHEM101    null              null
Math101    mathematics 1     5533
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're after all the courses with a degree_plan type of "SWE", and then the data from [equal] and [student] for student ID 5533.

```
SELECT courses .course,equal.equivalent ,equal.id 
FROM courses 
INNER JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.no =courses.no 
LEFT JOIN equal ON equal.Course_no=courses.course_no AND id=5533 
LEFT JOIN student ON courses.no= student.no 
WHERE degree_plan.major='SWE';
```

Try the above, I think you were close, but the columns you were bringing back were from [equal], not from [student] so if you want to filter them by the student ID put that on the JOIN clause for that table.

You don't actually appear to be using [student] in your resultset, so you could simplify to

```
SELECT courses .course,equal.equivalent ,equal.id 
FROM courses 
INNER JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.no =courses.no 
LEFT JOIN equal ON equal.Course_no=courses.course_no AND id=5533 
WHERE degree_plan.major='SWE';
```